# AnyLogic - use both sides for new storage object

Tags: anylogic

We just update our AnyLogic to 8.7.7. because there is new storage object that looked very promising. However, we are not able to make to accesible from both sides - current storage object can be accessed only from one side, as indicated by access area in AL help site here
https://anylogic.help/markup/storage.html#storage

Does anyone already know whether it supports such functionality of two-sided storage ?

More details:
In the link, there are screenshots indicating with "bold" line that storage is accessible only from one direction, I would need "double" storage accessible from both sides and changing the number of slots does not work

Edit: Storage system picture
[image: Storage system]

Right side of the storage system is "bold", indicating the back of the rack. I don't see any option to make these storages both sided, only to increase their depth.

Thank you

Comment: what do you mean by "from both sides"? For an individual rack? the entire storage system? Best add a screenshot to clarify :)

Comment: more info added into the question

Comment: which of the screenshots and what "bold" lines? Best upload your own explanatory screenshot somewhere and link to it here ;)

Comment: actual picture added